# Entity Framework code first TPH where discriminator is greater than 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I am defining a model in EF4 CTP5 where I need to map an inherited entity only when the value of an id is greater than 0. the code looks like this.

```
public class Parent
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
   public int SchoolID { get; set; }
}
```

In the OnModelCreating method...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Map<Child>(
            reg => 
                {
                reg.MapInheritedProperties();
                reg.Requires("SchoolID").HasValue((int)<value greater than 0); <== Pseudo code
            }).ToTable("Users");
```

Is this sort of thing possible? If not, is it possible to ignore the discriminator altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the 'is it possible' part, but it smells a little.  I mean, it implies meaning in your data where there really should not be meaning; you'll wind up with long term maintainability problems.  The discriminator is there not just to help the ORM figure out which record is of which type, it's also supposed to be (imo) a logical description of the type you're dealing with, for when humans run SQL queries against the db.  It also can be used to help with index partitioning.  I realize that TPH is a bit of denormalization anyway, but you still want to be able to design a well-indexed db with those in there.

I'd suggest just letting EF do the discriminator for you based on the type name, which iirc is the default.

Comment: I actually tried to let EF do the discriminator however I get an Invalid column name 'discriminator' error. In addition, I realize my example may be a bad one. It is not unusual however, for a table to use a hierarchical pointer such as a ParentId to point to a parent record in the same table where a 0 ParentId would indicate that you are at the top of the hierarchical structure. I am essentially just trying to do something similar.

Comment: What database are you using?  sounds like it has the word 'discriminator' as a keyword.  Anyway, you can override the discriminator column name & logic, via this example:  http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Comment: Ok, thanks to your suggestion and link I am closer. However, I still cannot get the discriminator to work as I would like. It seems like the only way you can override the logic behind the discriminator is to change the column used and the type. Is this correct? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure I follow you.  When you map the hierarchy explicitly, you declare the column name and the value that each type will have in that column.  So like you did, but it'll be a column that's specifically built to be a discriminator (rather than pulling double duty as an ID field), eg:  reg=>reg.Requires("SchoolType").HasValue("Child")

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Unfortuantely, this is a production db and not likely to be able to be changed for this purpose. Thank you!